# in Android Studio Error “duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1.class”

Tags: android-studio, gradle, google-analytics, google-play-services, android-gps

Here is my gradle code

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
    

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.mujihamzale.Ayat-AyatMerdu"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
}
```

But when running the application on android studio 2.1.3, I get the following error:

```js
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1.class
```

I have been for days to look for a solution, Please Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: delete `compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')` I guess it comes with `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'`

Comment: Thanks for responding @RalphBergmann. I had tried to delete it but it still didn't work

Comment: @RalphBergmann I deleted this files '('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')' like you said but i have got new error and more errors like this one 'Error:(22, 45) error: package com.google.analytics.tracking.android does not exist'

Comment: I tried it and without `compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')` it runs. Maybe you need to clean the project?

Comment: @RalphBergmann Thanks ralph it has been working fine